# Is it "keep your happy zone" and if so what does it mean?

Tags: meaning

Here is a comment by Christopher Hitchens:

https://youtu.be/nZUMGid0IvI?t=142

YouTube transcribed this as:

> Keep your happy zone

Is that correct? What would it mean? Is it a part of a longer phrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with that transcription, or it might be "keep in your happy zone".

It is an ironic comment.  Hitchins is ironically telling Heston to "stay happy", but if we listen to the context he means: "continue believing in what makes you happy (about the Iraq war,) (even if it isn't true)."

It is a subtle disrespect, suggesting that Heston is a bit of an idiot and can't distinguish between hopes and facts. The fact it is mumbled adds to the disrespect: "Your ideas are not even worth me speaking clearly!".  This is why the interviewer jumps in, to prevent further insults.

I would not call this a standard idiom, but the ironic intent is clear from the context. There are related phrases like "go to my happy place", which means "stop worrying about something and imagine something that makes me happy".